# How can i add a class with jquery in an input to add has-something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi guys i am trying to create a form with jquery validation for the display effects only.

```
  <div id="input_group_name" class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 has-feedback">
    <div class="input-group ">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
     <input id="name_input" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" autofocus="true" required="true">
     <span id="input_icon_feedback" class=""></span>
   </div>
</div>

var x = document.getElementById("btnCheckPersonalInfo");
    var y = document.getElementById("input_group_name");
    var i = document.getElementById("name_input");
    $(x).click(function(){
        if(i === ""){
            $(y).addClass("has-error");
        }else{

            $(y).addClass("has-success");
        }
```

I am just trying whene we click a btn the input field change the has-success to has-error whene a user submits a form.In this case just one input field!Sory for not being clear enought

Comment: In what way is it "*not working*"? Without those details, and enough of your HTML to reproduce your problem (see: "*[mcve]*") we're unable to help, since we can only guess, which is a waste of our time as well as yours. Although, speculatively, I'm going to guess that `i` can never be equal to `""`, since `i` - in the first block - is an element (or `null`) whereas `""` is a String.

Comment: Can you provide your html too.

Comment: Could you give us some more information, what are you trying to accomplish here and what exaclty is not working ?

Comment: Hi, what you mean by "it is not working". What do you expect ? The wrong class, no class at all ?

Comment: you're mixing jquery and javascript on the second one, you want `.value` rather than `val` or `$('#name_input').val();` and on the first one you're possibly missing `.value`, if I understand correctly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand, you could simply iterate through each elements of your forms and validate it. 
We don't know what kind of validation you are trying to do so let's say you're just trying to validate it is not empty.

```
$('#myform :input').each(function($index, $value) {
    if($($value).val() === "") {
        $($value).parent().addClass("has-error").removeClass("has-success");
    } else {
        $($value).parent().addClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error");
    }
})
```

Comment: `$value` is a DOM node, not a jQuery Object; and the classes are to be added to the parent `<div>` element, not the `<input>` itself (so far as I can tell from the posted, non-functional, JavaScript).